# Copy file without using standard library function in C

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, file-copying

How can I copy a file without using standard C library functions in Linux? In other words, I would like to copy a file directly with system calls. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Open the file for reading and the copy for writing.. The read and write. Use the non-standard low level platform specific functions if `fopen` etc aren't allowed.

Comment: Sure.  What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: Sorry I dod not mentioned it. I want to do it in Linux 64.

Comment: Then use `open`, `read`, `write` and `close`. They are all in section `2` in the `man` pages.

Comment: It's almost as easy as `fopen`/`fread`/`fwrite`/`fclose`.  (A smidge easier, actually: four fewer `f`'s to type, and one fewer argument to `read` and `write`, too! :-) )

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Technically, the normal way to use those from C are via the wrapper functions defined in `libc.so`; it's slightly ambiguous whether the querent means without any functions from libc, or without any functions that ISO C defines as "library" functions.  There's some implication of the latter, in which case yes, POSIX standard functions would work fine.  Otherwise you'd want to use a header that would actually inline the syscalls (with inline `asm` statements) so you don't need to link libc, such as https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/linux-syscall-support (has all arches, including x86

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, using syscalls would probably be an even safer way to score on this assignment.

Comment: To Peter's point: this question was originally tagged with [assembly], until I (perhaps wrongly) deleted it.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Ah, that would make sense, then.  Writing by hand in asm makes the difference between calling a function vs. calling the kernel directly more obvious than the normal C way of using a wrapper function for your inline asm.  But if you know the system-calling convention ([What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989)), you just need to know which system calls at all, and then you can look up their man pages to find where the args go, and call numbers from `unistd_64.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> file directly with system calls. Is it possible?

In pseudocode, using `sendfile`:

```
int in = open("input", ...);
fstatat(in, &stat);
int out = open("output", ...);
sendfile(in, out, NULL, stat.st_size);
```

Comment: You should call `sendfile` in a loop. It may not send all the bytes, and in that case needs to be restarted.

Comment: Also, note the man-page caution - `"Other Unix systems implement sendfile() with different semantics and prototypes. It should not be used in portable programs."` That said, if you do not need it to be portable, `sendfile()` is very fast and efficient due to the transfer being done in kernel space.

Comment: Fun fact: on Linux 5.3 and later, there's [`copy_file_range(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html) which takes two FDs, two offsets, and a length.  But like sendfile, it can still return early with fewer bytes copied than requested, so should still be called in a loop.  (The syscall was present since 4.5, but before 5.3 it would return -EXDEV if the files weren't on the same FS.  I think it was originally intended for making CoW reflinks like on btrfs / zfs like `cp --reflink=auto` does, but now can fall back to an in-kernel copy.)  Does sendfile do CoW?